# What is the similar term for 'fraud' in a positive sense?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine I bought something, but instead of giving me worse product for what I'm paying, the seller gives me a far better product for my price, without my knowledge. Is there any term for this?

Comment: Does the seller know they're selling the item for far less than it's worth?

Comment: Can you Post a phrase meaning exactly what you seek in your own, or any other language? How could there be, partly because the gap between 'fraud' and anything even positive, let alone not criminal is far too large? If you insist, 'generosity' might work but that's more about your insistence than anything in the English language.

Answer (score -1):

The context of the question is not specified, but when it comes to marketing, there are several terms for that.

**[Predatory pricing](https://www.sniffie.io/pricing-vocabulary/predatory-pricing/)**

> Predatory pricing refers to a pricing strategy where a business lowers its prices significantly below the cost of production and sells its products or services, with the intention of driving competitors out of the market.

**[Penetration Pricing](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/penetration-pricing.asp)**

> Penetration pricing is a marketing strategy used by businesses to attract customers to a new product or service by offering a lower price during its initial offering. The lower price helps a new product or service penetrate the market and attract customers away from competitors.

**[Loss Leader Strategy](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/lossleader.asp)**

> A loss leader strategy involves selling a product or service at a price that is not profitable but is sold to attract new customers or to sell additional products and services to those customers. Loss leading is a common practice when a business first enters a market.